# GridView doesn't fit whole screen

Tags: android, gridview, calendar

I have created a custom calendar for my application, that looks like this:

[image]
The problem is that it doesn't fill the entire hieght of the screen.

To make the calendar I've used a GridView with a custom adapter where i set the height of each cell like this:

```
int other = 56 + 30 + 50 + statusBarHeight;
currCell.getLayoutParams().height = (screenHeight - other) / MAX_ROW;
```

Where:

56 is the height (set in dp inside the layout file) of the toolbar;

30 is the height (set in dp inside the layout file) of the layout that displays the names of the days;

50 is the height (set in dp inside the layout file) of the bottom bar;

statusBarHeight is the height of the status bar, calculated with:

```
statusBarHeight = 0;
int statusBarId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (statusBarId > 0)
    statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(statusBarId);
```

screenHeight is the height of the screen, calculated with:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

MAX_ROW is equal to 7.

The other problem is that when I try the application on a different phone the GridView still doesn't fit the screen but in a different way. For example, the phone in the picture is a Honor9. On a LG G4 the grid is longer than the screen while on an emulated Nexus 5X it's way shorter.

I'm looking for a method to set programmatically the height of the cells that makes the grid fit perfectly the screen on each device.

Thanks in advance :)